# Handle json response in 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am into some weird situation where JSON response is-

```
{"Id":1,"service_name":"asdf","service_charge":11.32,"service_type":null,"service_comission":14.65,"service_desc":"","after_service_charge":23.55,"service_duration":60,"after_service_comission":11.22,"service_frequency":58,"tax_rate":15}
```

**Condition-**
In my form- `#form-service-values` I have input field of same name as it comes in response. Now I wanted to fetch value from `JSON` where data name matches.
For ex-

`data.service_name` logs me with value `asdf`

But Now here It is coming to me when name is dynamic of input fields as-
`[object Object].service_name`

Here Is how I am handling it in ajax-

```
 function getDescService(Idservice) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Service/GetServiceDescriptions/',
            type: 'post',
            data: { Id: Idservice },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#form-service-values input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    $(this).val(data + "." + name);
                })

            }
        });
    }
```

I am trying to get this JSON response in a form where name of `inputs` are same as it comes in `JSON` response.

I just want to access `JSON` data fields. 
How do I try on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, an object can be access like that `data.name`, where name is the key, or like that `data["name"]`

So you should do this

```
$(this).val(data[name]);
```

Instead of this

```
$(this).val(data + "." + name);
```

The first one is retrieving the value stored at the key `name` in the object `data`, while the second one is only writing text.